# How to Maintain All Headers Through Reverse Proxy with Caddy

Tags: reverse-proxy, caddy

I am using Caddy as a reverse proxy so that I only need to have 2 ports open in my gateway (one for http and one for https).

I would prefer to use `80` and `443`, but my UniFi USG (Gateway) interferes with 443 and breaks SSL. If I choose another port and add a Port Forward for that, it works fine... but this is unreasonable for every server route I need because my firewall will turn into swiss cheese.

So a reverse proxy is perfect for this. I will only have 2 ports open: `88` and `444` that go to the reverse proxy.  In Caddy, I can easily set the destination port in the Caddyfile:

```json
// DNS points to the gateway's IP
mysubdomain.mydomain.com {
    reverse_proxy {
      to https://192.168.1.IP:443
      transport http {
          read_buffer 4096
      }
    {
}
```

#### Question

In my first attempt, my SSL wasn't working (thanks to proxy-modified headers), so I looked at the [Caddy Reverse Proxy Headers](https://caddyserver.com/docs/caddyfile/directives/reverse_proxy#headers) documentation and found they do modify 2 headers:

- It adds or augments the `X-Forwarded-For` header field.
- It sets the `X-Forwarded-Proto` header field.

What values do I use so that Caddy passes on the original, or doesn't add anything?

#### Current Config

Here's what I currently have, what should I be using to make sure the X-Forwarded headers are not changed or added?

```json
mysubdomain.mydomain.com {
    reverse_proxy {
      to https://192.168.1.IP:443
      transport http {
          read_buffer 4096
      }
    {
    header_up Host {http.request.host}
    header_up X-Real-IP {http.request.remote.host}
    header_up X-Forwarded-For { ?? }
    header up X-Forwarded-Port { ?? }
    header_up X-Forwarded-Proto { ?? }
}
```

Follow up question: Are there other settings I should use in addition to the ones I have set?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do it

```
https://mysubdomain.mydomain.com {
    reverse_proxy localhost:8080 {
        header_up Host {host} # redundant
        header_up X-Real-IP {remote}
        header_up X-Forwarded-For {remote}  # redundant
        header_up X-Forwarded-Port {server_port} # redundant
        header_up X-Forwarded-Proto {scheme}
      }
}
```

The ones marked redundant are the default, see
https://github.com/caddyserver/caddy/issues/2873

Comment: Thank you, it does work in my test lab setup. Though I did get rid of Caddy and switched to Nginx Proxy Manager instead. It's significantly better than Caddy for easy certificate and proxy host management, also you get a nice GUI.